# Answer score on MSE different from score seen on MO profile

Tags: bug, mathoverflow, profile-page

My answer to the question [What is wrong with the sum of these two series?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1081892/what-is-wrong-with-the-sum-of-these-two-series/1081894#1081894) currently has a score of $39$. However, on my [MathOverflow profile](https://mathoverflow.net/users/21564/michael-albanese?tab=profile), it shows that it has a score of $40$ in the 'Top Network Posts' section. Any idea what's going on here?

Comment: The same bug has been reported on [Meta StackExchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256398/post-score-in-the-top-network-posts-borked-somewhere) and on [Meta StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345079/top-network-posts-showing-wrong-score), neither of which have successfully found the source of the problem.

Comment: @projectilemotion : I'd have said "Neither has found" rather than "Neither have found."

Comment: See http://shouldiblamecaching.com/. Anyway, it seems to have updated by now; at least I see a score of 39 in both places.